# Passing environment variable to docker image at build time with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, versioning

Everything I tried following [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) and [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) references to pass an environment variable to the Docker image did not work.

I want to make this env var available during docker build when using docker-compose.

On the Docker host I have:

```
export BUILD_VERSION=1.0
```

**app.js**

```
console.log('BUILD_VERSION: ' + process.env.BUILD_VERSION);
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node
ADD app.js /
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION
RUN node /app.js
CMD echo Run Time: $BUILD_VERSION
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BUILD_VERSION
```

If I build the image directly, the env var is passed fine:

```
docker build -t test --no-cache --build-arg BUILD_VERSION .
```

and is also available at run-time:

```
$ docker run --rm test
Run Time: 1.0
$ docker run --rm test node /app
BUILD_VERSION: 1.0
```

but not with docker compose.

```
docker-compose up --build

...
Step 5/7 : RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION
 ---> Running in 6115161f33bf
Build Time:
 ---> c691c619018a
Removing intermediate container 6115161f33bf
Step 6/7 : RUN node /app.js
 ---> Running in f51831cc5e1e
BUILD_VERSION:
```

It's only available at run-time:

```
$ docker run --rm test
Run Time: 1.0
$ docker run --rm test node /app
BUILD_VERSION: 1.0
```

I also tried using `environment` in docker-compose.yml like below which again only makes it available at run-time but not build-time:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - BUILD_VERSION
```

Please advise, how can I make it work in the least convoluted way?

Comment: as long as Dockerfile has ENV AA=$BB  and previously you have done your export BB=CC there is no need for yaml to mention args nor any command line  build-arg

Comment: @ScottStensland Tried that too; didn't work. :(

Comment: I do not use docker-compose to build an image, only to launch or bring down its containers ... to build I issue ... docker build --tag  foo --no-cache .
... followed by ...  docker push foo  ... to me contents of docker-compose yaml file are runtime settings and it conflates and over complicates to have it also control the build especially when you have many containers which have disparate rebuild criteria versus launch

Comment: I agree it's best to keep all build tasks in Dockerfile, as long as it works when called through docker-compose. But I haven't found a working solution yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example is working for me.

Have you tried deleting the images and building again? Docker won't re-build your image despite environment variables changed if the image is in cache.

You can delete them with:

```
 docker-compose down --rmi all
```

---

Edit, I show here how it is working for me at build time:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BUILD_VERSION
```

Build:

```
$ export BUILD_VERSION=122221
$ docker-compose up --build
Creating network "a_default" with the default driver
Building app
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
8e3ba11ec2a2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7043076348bf5040220df6ad703798fd8593a0918d06d3ce30c6c93be117e430
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/4 : ARG BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in b0a1a79967a0
Removing intermediate container b0a1a79967a0
---> 9fa331d63f6d
Step 3/4 : ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in a602c27689a5
Removing intermediate container a602c27689a5
---> bf2181423c93
Step 4/4 : RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION                <<<<<< (*)
---> Running in 9d828cefcfab
Build Time: 122221
Removing intermediate container 9d828cefcfab
---> 2b3afa3d348c
Successfully built 2b3afa3d348c
Successfully tagged a_app:latest
Creating a_app_1 ... done
Attaching to a_app_1
a_app_1 exited with code 0
```

---

As the other answer mentioned, you can use `docker-compose build --no-cache`, and you can avoid mentioning "app" if you have multiple services, so docker-compose will build all the services. What you can do to handle different build versions in the same `docker-compose build` is to use different env vars, like:

```
$ cat docker-compose
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BUILD_VERSION=$APP1_BUILD_VERSION
  app2:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BUILD_VERSION=$APP2_BUILD_VERSION
```

Export:

```
$ export APP1_BUILD_VERSION=1.1.1
$ export APP2_BUILD_VERSION=2.2.2
```

Build:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building app1
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
8e3ba11ec2a2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7043076348bf5040220df6ad703798fd8593a0918d06d3ce30c6c93be117e430
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/4 : ARG BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in 0b66093bc2ef
Removing intermediate container 0b66093bc2ef
---> 906130ee5da8
Step 3/4 : ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in 9d89b48c875d
Removing intermediate container 9d89b48c875d
---> ca2480695149
Step 4/4 : RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in 52dec27874ec
Build Time: 1.1.1
Removing intermediate container 52dec27874ec
---> 1b3654924297
Successfully built 1b3654924297
Successfully tagged a_app1:latest
Building app2
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine
---> 11cd0b38bc3c
Step 2/4 : ARG BUILD_VERSION
---> Using cache
---> 906130ee5da8
Step 3/4 : ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in d29442339459
Removing intermediate container d29442339459
---> 8b26def5ef3a
Step 4/4 : RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION
---> Running in 4b3de2d223e5
Build Time: 2.2.2
Removing intermediate container 4b3de2d223e5
---> 89033b10b61e
Successfully built 89033b10b61e
Successfully tagged a_app2:latest
```

Comment: At run-time, the env var is available. I need to have it at build-time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set argument in docker-compose.yml as shown which will then be overriden to passed env variable -

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BUILD_VERSION
```

Next export environment variable you need to pass.

```
$ export BUILD_VERSION=1.0
```

Now build the image using command

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION app
```

Comment: It works even without the dummy value with using `docker build` command, as I mentioned. But I need it to work with `docker-compose`.

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you try this out if it works!

Comment: It worked! But I hoped I could do it in one step with `docker-compose up`. With this when I have multiple services in `docker-compose.yml` I have to build the images separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in args to build, from the docker-compose file to the docker build. It is surprising the env vars aren't used for run *and* build.

```
// docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
app:
  build:
    context: .
environment:
  - BUILD_VERSION
args:
  - BUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION}
volumes:
       ...
// Dockerfile
FROM node
ADD app.js /
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ENV BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION
RUN echo Build Time: $BUILD_VERSION
RUN node /app.js
CMD echo Run Time: $BUILD_VERSION
```